# Asynchronous method in the background in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, background, thrift

I want to be able to send data while not blocking the UI. These files are quite big, so synchronously sending them is not an option.

I have a class that implements all the methods of sending data through Apache Thrift.

All the asynchronous requests I've seen are using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection, but for my application I want to utilize my class.

Basically, I want to asynchronously call this method:

```
- (void)syncLocalData {
    Manager *stateManager = [[Manager alloc] init];
    [stateManager readDirectory];
}
```

In readDirectory, I go through the device directory and send over data if there is a file.

Comment: What is your question? How to "go through the device directory"? How to "send over data"? How to call your method asynchronously?

Comment: I've implemented going through the directory and sending over the data. I just want to be able to call my method asynchronously.

Comment: I'm wondering why did you wrap inherent asynchronous network requests into a synchronous helper method in the first place? I would simply invoke the network requests asynchronously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) offers easy-to-use functions to execute code asynchronously
on a background thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [yourInstance syncLocalData];
});
```

Depending on your needs, you can use the global queue (which is a "concurrent" queue),
or create your own "serial" queue.

Comment: Awesome, this seems to work! How would you handle cases where the user might exit the application while it's in midst of sending data?

Comment: Well, then you need even more awesome asynchronous and cancelable network requests which you hold in an array (or NSOperationQueue) and access them in case you want cancel them.

Comment: You can subscribe to the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification if you want to do any clean-up.

Comment: Thanks, Martin R!

One last question: I used the dispatch_async method to call a method to send the data asynchronously, but if it fails (network error), it will show a UIAlert.

I realize that this now crashes the application, most likely because it's a UI method.

What do you propose I do to show the UIAlert?

Comment: So after googling around, I found this method:

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`

which seemed to do the job.